# Any SE for "Why does the Shanghai Maglev train cabin have a power bar and a portable fan?"

Tags: discussion

Where would [Why does the Shanghai Maglev train cabin have a power bar and a portable fan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/120272/13759) be on-topic?

Comment: Nowhere, as I see it. 'Why' questions do not fit with the structure of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: If there were a "Railways StackExchange," perhaps there, in the same way that we cover the passenger aspects of air travel but Aviation handles the details of aircraft themselves.

Comment: "Power bar" is new to me, it seems to be a Canadian term. So, you have no idea why a first class (?) compartment would supply its passengers (by the looks of it business class) the use of a power board/power bar?  So that you can charge your smartphone, use your laptop, watch a DVD on a player and possibly, have a fan on, all at the same time?